# compiling the package [costmap_2d] is extremely slow on Jetson TK1

Tags: ros, navigation, costmap-2d, linking

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have anyone experienced compiling `costmap_2d` on a Nvidia Jetson TK1 with Ubuntu 16.04 and ROS Kinetic? I've tried to compile it on 2 such boards. They all compiled very very slow!
In the extreme case, I tried to compile `costmap_2d` in my own catkin workspace with the command `catkin_make` with or without `-j5`, `--use-ninja`. In this case, `costmap_2d` simply failed to finish compiling. It stuck at

```
Linking CXX executable /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/costmap_2d/costmap_2d_cloud
Linking CXX executable /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/costmap_2d/costmap_2d_markers
```

The linking procedure lasts forever, never succeed to accomplish.

The only way I made it finish is by invoking `catkin_make_isolated` instead of `catkin_make`, and the linking still takes very long time when compared to other packages (like lasting 10min+ or so).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250868/compiling-the-package-%5Bcostmap_2d%5D-is-extremely-slow-on-jetson-tk1/) by [ZOU Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/28803/zou-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 143 on 2016-12-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have finally succeeded to compile `costmap_2d` with `catkin_make` alone. Just push my patience to the extreme, and it took 40+ minutes to link to success!

Still, can any one kindly point out why is this happening, any hints will be appreciated. Thanks!

---

Originally posted by [ZOU Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/28803/zou-lu/) with karma: 143 on 2016-12-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-12-29**:
Linking can be a very RAM-intensive process; perhaps your system is using swap while linking?

**Comment by [ZOU Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/28803/zou-lu/) on 2016-12-29**:
Thank you for answering!
It probably didn't used the swap, the TK1 has 4GB memory. And I even tried to compiled with only one thread (`-j1`). I also tried `free -m` to see memory consumption, there are more than 2GB free memory available.